# error encountered on following path slices

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js, vercel

all functions as expected on DEV. However in build, I keep getting this error. The items are queried items from contentful, the pages and data are loading fine but this error keeps pointing towards my redux cartslice. Any ideas?

FUNCTION

import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

```
const initialState = {
items: [],
};

const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: "basket",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
      addToBasket: (state, action) => {
          state.items = [...state.items, action.payload] 
      },
      removeFromBasket: (state, action) => {},

  },
});

export const {addToBasket, removeFromBasket} = cartSlice.actions

export const selectItems = (state) => state.basket.items;

export default cartSlice.reducer
```

ERROR

```
at C:\Users\Owner\nextjs-strapi-tailwind\node_modules\next\dist\export\index.js:498:19
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (C:\Users\Owner\nextjs-strapi-tailwind\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:75:20)
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (C:\Users\Owner\nextjs-strapi-tailwind\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:75:20)
    at async C:\Users\Owner\nextjs-strapi-tailwind\node_modules\next\dist\build\index.js:1024:17
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (C:\Users\Owner\nextjs-strapi-tailwind\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:75:20)
    at async C:\Users\Owner\nextjs-strapi-tailwind\node_modules\next\dist\build\index.js:898:13
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (C:\Users\Owner\nextjs-strapi-tailwind\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:75:20)
    at async Object.build [as default] (C:\Users\Owner\nextjs-strapi-tailwind\node_modules\next\dist\build\index.js:82:25)
```

Answer (score 1):

My slices folder was in the pages folder. Moved it outside of this and it solved the error. Nonpage components should be outside of pages